# How to load values in text box from Angular js

Tags: html, angularjs

I've UI table in HTML where i can display records i'm fetching from DB by Angular Js.

Scenario : I've a text box where i'll select the id and related fields are displaying in table it mapped with for particular id.

```
<td>Name</td>
<td>{{Name}}</td>
```

Expected : I want it to be displayed in text boxes instead of table so that i can edit it.

```
Name : <input type="text" value=?????/>
```

how can i achieve it. will ng-bind helps???

Comment: Thnks friends......it worked as u suggested.

Comment: accept someone answer which is appropriate for your problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User input text box like the two below

```
  <input type="text" value="{{name}}"/>
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="name"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="text" ng-model="Name" />
```